# Removing Duplicate Error Messages From Validation Summary Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have situation where I have a number of validators with the same error message on a page, when the page is validated these duplicates are shown in the validation summary.

I would like to remove these duplicates from the validation summary server side.

Here's some pseudo code of what I'd like to do.

```
validationSummery.ErrorMessages = validationSummery.ErrorMessages.DistinctBy(x=>x.ErrorText);
```

Having looked into the validation control it appears there is no access to the messages it displays.

I could iterate over all of the page validators which are invalid before the validation summary gets to them and set only one of each message type to valid but then I would not get the error message next to each control.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: if various validators show the same message, I think there is a problem in your implementation. Fix that

Comment: Jasen Nope, no duplicate name attributes @Dan The implementation is that a range of text boxes needed to add up to a total of 100. All of them will be wrong if the values don't add up and I want a 'all totals must add up to X' next to each textbox.

Comment: Then just show only the summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty but with the use of dotPeek to get the source for the ValidationSummary along with a bit of reflection I created a UniqueMessageValidationSummary control.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Extended version of Validation Summary which overrides OnRender and re-implements get error
    /// messages method to ensure the control only renders unique error messages.
    /// 
    /// Utilizes .NET code cleaned from .Peek and reflection to access subclass     
    /// </summary>
    public class UniqueMessageValidationSummary : ValidationSummary 
    {
        internal string[] GetErrorMessages(out bool inError)
        {
            var strArray = (string[])null;
            inError = false;
            var length = 0;
            var validators = Page.GetValidators(ValidationGroup);
            for (var index = 0; index < validators.Count; ++index)
            {
                var validator = validators[index];
                if (!validator.IsValid)
                {
                    inError = true;
                    if (validator.ErrorMessage.Length != 0)
                        ++length;
                }
            }
            if (length != 0)
            {
                strArray = new string[length];
                var index1 = 0;
                for (var index2 = 0; index2 < validators.Count; ++index2)
                {
                    var validator = validators[index2];
                    if (!validator.IsValid && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(validator.ErrorMessage))
                    {
                        strArray[index1] = string.Copy(validator.ErrorMessage);
                        ++index1;
                    }
                }
            }

            var uniqueErrors = new List<string>();

            if (strArray != null)
            {
               var objRegExp = new Regex("<(.|\n)+?>");       
                foreach (var error in strArray)
                {
                    if (uniqueErrors.All(x => objRegExp.Replace(error, string.Empty) != objRegExp.Replace(x, String.Empty)))
                    {
                        uniqueErrors.Add(error);
                    }
                }
            }

            return uniqueErrors.ToArray();
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            var renderUplevelCopy = true;

            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

            var baseType = GetType().BaseType;

            if (baseType != null)
            {
                var field = baseType.GetField("renderUplevel", flags);
                if (field != null)
                    renderUplevelCopy = (bool)field.GetValue(this);
            }  

            string[] strArray;
            bool flag1;
            if (DesignMode)
            {
                flag1 = true;
                renderUplevelCopy = false;
                strArray = new[]
                    {
                      "ValSummary_error_message_1",
                      "ValSummary_error_message_2"
                    };
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Enabled)
                    return;
                bool inError;
                strArray = GetErrorMessages(out inError);
                flag1 = ShowSummary && inError;
                if (!flag1 && renderUplevelCopy)
                    Style["display"] = "none";
            }
            if (Page != null)
                Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(this);
            var flag2 = renderUplevelCopy || flag1;
            if (flag2)
                RenderBeginTag(writer);
            if (flag1)
            {
                string text1;
                string str1;
                string str2;
                string text2;
                string text3;
                switch (DisplayMode)
                {
                    case ValidationSummaryDisplayMode.List:
                        text1 = "b";
                        str1 = string.Empty;
                        str2 = string.Empty;
                        text2 = "b";
                        text3 = string.Empty;
                        break;
                    case ValidationSummaryDisplayMode.SingleParagraph:
                        text1 = " ";
                        str1 = string.Empty;
                        str2 = string.Empty;
                        text2 = " ";
                        text3 = "b";
                        break;
                    default:
                        text1 = string.Empty;
                        str1 = "<ul>";
                        str2 = "<li>";
                        text2 = "</li>";
                        text3 = "</ul>";
                        break;
                }
                if (HeaderText.Length > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(HeaderText);
                    WriteBreakIfPresent(writer, text1);
                }
                if (strArray != null)
                {
                    writer.Write(str1);
                    foreach (var t in strArray)
                    {
                        writer.Write(str2);
                        writer.Write(t);
                        WriteBreakIfPresent(writer, text2);
                    }
                    WriteBreakIfPresent(writer, text3);
                }
            }
            if (!flag2)
                return;
            RenderEndTag(writer);
        }

        private static void WriteBreakIfPresent(HtmlTextWriter writer, string text)
        {
            if (text == "b")
            {
                writer.WriteBreak();
            }
            else
                writer.Write(text);
        }
    }
```